# Moving column references in active formulas +1 per button click

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to get VBA to take a simple SUM formula in a sheet, but each time you click the command button, the column references shift to the right by one column. I am using the below for each formula, but the code is not remembering the previous formula references, and shifting the C reference across one column each time you click.

```
Dim AA As Integer
AA = Sheet5.Range("Q" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Sheet5.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[99]:RC[110])"
Sheet5.Range("A3").Copy
Sheet5.Range("A3:A" & AA).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

So each time you click the command Button, these references in the SUM formula go:

```
  'Click
  "=SUM(RC[99]:RC[110])"
  'Click
  "=SUM(RC[100]:RC[111])"
  'Click
  "=SUM(RC[101]:RC[112])"
  'Click
  "=SUM(RC[102]:RC[113])"
  'Click
  "=SUM(RC[103]:RC[114])"
```

Comment: You are mentioning columns, but are referring to rows in your example, where is the code that changes the formula?

Comment: Sheet5.Range("A3").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[99]:RC[110])"

Comment: I don't see how that's trying to make the formula move?

Comment: That's the problem, I am trying to make the columns change by +1 for the SUM formula, so when you click the command button, the sum range shifts across by one column

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "command button"?

Comment: Command Button (ActiveX Control)

Comment: So you've not tried anything, but setting it to the same range?  You need to have a go, then come back.  Look at public and static variables

Comment: I have being trying different things for the past two hours thanks.